# Is there any Custom facebook script for personal website?

Tags: php

I am working on website like facebook. In which i need to post video, images and post status and there is like,comment option for all posts same like facebook. So my question is there any custom script opensource so i can implement into my website.I did some googling but doesn't get any script like that.If any one knows about this script then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wordpress](http://wordpress.org) + [Buddypress plugin](https://buddypress.org/) could be a solution.

Obviously, nothing is going to have the exact Facebook functionality off the shelf.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jomsocial for create this type of site. but no one script find which bind your all requirement about create this type of website